# The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I get some error of release version of application:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403    Forbidden
{  
   "code":403,
   "errors":[  
      {  
         "domain":"usageLimits",
         "message":"Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
         "reason":"accessNotConfigured",
         "extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com"
      }
   ],
   "message":"Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
}
```

My test version work on test account,  and in google develeper console enabled Google Calendar API - its work fine. But, when I generate apk, this error was appeared. Where I can enabled google calendar api? Can I use my ssh1 repeatedly to create access for release version in another account?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to also add any *release* keystore SHA1 to the Google Developer Console.

You can place it on a new line below that of your debug key.

The following command will generate the SHA1 for you once you replace the fields with the relevant details for your keystore

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <your-keystore-path> -alias <keystore-alias> -storepass <store-pass> -keypass <key-pass>
```